# How to pass the parameters to T4 templates using pre build event command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, t4, pre-build-event

I need to pass the parameter from my prebuild event to my T4 template. Currently i am using following Pre-build command to build my T4 template file but i am not able to pass parameter to it.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\texttransform.exe" "$(ProjectDir)VersionGenerator.tt"
```

I need to pass the parameter to my VersionGenerator.tt template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `TextTransform.exe` there's a command-line switch for passing parameters to t4 templates: `-a` which accept parameters in the following format:

```
-a [processorName]![directiveName]!<parameterName>!<parameterValue>
```

When using, consider:

- You can resolve the parameter by [`Host.ResolveParameterValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bb126369(v=vs.110)).
- processorName and directiveName are optional and you can omit them.
- You always need type the '!' marks, even if you omit the optional processor and directive names.
- For each parameter that you want to pass, you need one `-a` switch.
- You can use `""` around switch value.
- For more information about Take a look at [Generate files with the TextTransform utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generating-files-with-the-texttransform-utility).

**Example**

Assuming you have the following template `Template1.tt`:

```
<#@ template hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<# string param1 = this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "param1"); #>   
param1 : <#= param1 #>
```

The following command:

```
texttransform.exe "Template1.tt" -a "!!param1!value1"
```

Results in:

```
param1 : value1
```

**What should be Pre-build event command line?**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\texttransform.exe" "$(ProjectDir)Template1.tt" -a "!!param1!value1"
```

**Want more parameters?**

Just define them in template and pass them usinganother `-a` switch:

```
texttransform.exe "Template1.tt" -a "!!param1!value1" -a "!!param2!value2"
```

Comment: This is off-topic and is a different solution, but you can consider this solution for running t4 templates at build time: [Invoke text transformation in the build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Whether the argument name passed in the `this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "Foo")` is case sensitive or not.  Could you please explain.

Comment: @Venkat At leas in my test it showed it's not case-sensitive.

Comment: @Vinod Kumar since you are the original poster, it would be great if you can verify the answer :)

Comment: I am using `try { changeset = this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("-", "-", "changeset"); ` and this parameter is the second one, not the only one, I pass the 2 parameters like this and only the second one is empty...whereas the first parameter is totally fine. Passing both: `-a "!!buildConfiguration!$(ConfigurationName)" -a "!!changeset!asdasd"`